# How to print multiple variables associated with a username?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
def usernameresults():
    username2 = input("Please input the username you want to explore: ")
    leaderboardfile = open("leaderboard.txt","r")
    lbfrec = leaderboardfile.readline()
    while lbfrec != "":
        field = lbfrec.split(",")
        usernames = field[0]
        topic = field[1]
        difficult = field[2]
        scores = field[3]
        percentages = field[4]
        grades = field[5]
        if usernames != username2:
            print("Error, username not found")
            break
        else:
            print("These are the search results:\nUsername is ",usernames, "\nTopic is ",topic,
              "\nDifficulty is ",difficult, "\nNumber of questions correct are ",scores,
              "\nThe percentage is",percentages, "\nThe grade is ",grades)
            lbfrec = leaderboardfile.readline()
    leaderboardfile.close()
```

The code above is supposed to print out all of the information associated with the username inputted, however, it only prints one batch of the information even though there are multiple variables associated with that username in the file, how do i get the program to print out all of the information associated with the username instead of just one line?

```
in the file (leaderboard.txt) = 
 aad15,maths,Easy,3,100,A  <-- only prints this
 aad15,history,Easy,3,100,A  <-- but not this (i want it to print both)
 mas15,history,Hard,5,100,A
```

Comment: because you're only printing first line explicitly

Comment: How do i change that?

Comment: Apparently `usernames = field[0]` is the problem...

Comment: What is the problem with usernames = field[0] @KeiMinagawa ?

Comment: @SkidSolo:`usernames` never changes unless `field[0]` changes. It seems `field[0]` don't change in "while-loop", so `usernames` don't change...

Answer (score 0):

`if usernames != username2:` is happening the first iteration of the loop.

If you entered a name that's not on the first line, you're saying that the name isn't there, and you're ending the program without ever reading the remainder of the file.

You want `continue` instead of `break`

---

The following code assumes that you have unique names in the first column and it's an example of reading the whole file, and breaks when you find the name

```
def usernameresults():
    username2 = input("Please input the username you want to explore: ")
    found_userline = None
    with open("leaderboard.txt") as leaderboardfile:
        for line in leaderboardfile:

            field = line.split(",")
            username = field[0]

            if username == username2:
                print("username found")
                found_userline = line 
                break

    if found_userline is not None:
        topic, difficult, scores, percentages, grades = found_userline.split(',')[1:]
        print("These are the search results:\nUsername is ",usernames, "\nTopic is ",topic,
          "\nDifficulty is ",difficult, "\nNumber of questions correct are ",scores,
          "\nThe percentage is",percentages, "\nThe grade is ",grades)
    else:
        print("{} not found".format(username2))
```

If you want to print **all** lines where the first column is equal to your input, then don't break the loop... Just ignore the rows not equal, and store an additional list of all matching lines

This is also easy to do using Pandas library to filter out the rows